# Cannot convert X type to T. Generic delegate inside generic class

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Consider the following code:

```
delegate void SomeDelegate<in T>(T foo) where T : Foo;

class Foo { }

class SomeGenericClass<T> where T:Foo
{
    private readonly SomeDelegate<T> _action = _ => Console.WriteLine("Foo");

    public void DoStuff()=> _action(new Foo()); //here is the compiler error
}
```

The code is self-explanatory, I have this empty Foo class. Then I define a generic delegate with a generic constraint so that the type parameter will be always a **Foo**. Then we have a simple generic class with the same constraint as the delegate and inside it we have a generic delegate field. **DoStuff** invokes this delegate and passes a new instance of **Foo**.

Why this does not compile? I mean, I know why, the compiler is telling me:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ConsoleForSimpleTests.Program.Foo' to 'T'

The question rather is: why the compiler can not convert Foo to T given the generics constraints defined? why an explicit cast is needed here?

Suppose I add the following class: `class Boo:Foo { }`

There are two ways I can make things work:

**First:** We declare the generic delegate field to be of `Foo` explicitly. In this case I do not even need the generic type parameter in `SomeGenericClass`

```
class SomeGenericClass<T> where T:Foo
{
    private readonly SomeDelegate<Foo> _action = _ => Console.WriteLine("Foo");

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _action(new Foo());
        _action(new Boo());
    }
}
```

**Second:** We keep `T` but I have always to cast first to base class and then to T (casting directly to T does not compile for derived classes)

```
class SomeGenericClass<T> where T:Foo
{
    private readonly SomeDelegate<T> _action = _ => Console.WriteLine("Foo");

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _action((T)new Foo());
        _action((T)(Foo)new Boo());
    }
}
```

### Edit

Suppose I change `DoStuff` to:

```
public void DoStuff(T foo)
{
    _action(foo);
}
```

Testing:

```
var genericInstance = new SomeGenericClass<Foo>();
var foo = new Foo();
var boo = new Boo();
genericInstance.DoStuff(foo);
genericInstance.DoStuff(boo);
```

And everything is fine; what is the difference to adding those instances inside `DoStuff` directly?

```
public void DoStuff(T foo)
{
    _action(foo);
    _action(new Foo()); //does not compile
}
```

### Edit

Regarding the answer and comments of @Rawling:

Adding a class Moo => `class Moo{}` which does not inherit from Foo, regarding the fact that my work around may lead to a runtime exception:

```
public void DoStuff(T foo)
{
    _action(foo);
    _action((T)new Foo());
    _action((T)(Foo)new Boo());
    _action((T)(Foo)new Moo()); //this does not even compile
}
```

Comment: `T` is *not* `Foo`, can be `Foo` only if you create an instance of `SomeGenericClass<Foo>`. That's for the same reason you cannot `Add` an `object` in a `List<string>`. To accomplish what you want you may just add the constraint `new()` to your generic type, and do `_action(new T())` inside your method.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma thanks for your help!. You are right, adding new T() constraint is another workaround. But I think you are wrong when saying T is not Foo. T is always a Foo, after all that is why a generic type constraint is, isn't?

Comment: Given that constraint in `SomeGenericClass<T>` I can only create instances of `SomeGenericClass<Foo>` or of types derived from Foo =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` could be a type derived from `Foo`, in which case passing a `new Foo()` to `SomeDelegate<T>` is not safe. The delegate may try to access members of `T` that do not exist on a `Foo`.

Your first workaround works, but you may find your delegate cannot do everything it could before the workaround, as it now takes a `Foo`, not a `T`.

Your second workaround may lead to a runtime exception.

Comment: thanks a lot. First, why passing a most derived class is not safe? Here T is Foo. In the delegate handler, in this case the lambda, I can only access properties of Foo since the parameter of that lambda is Foo. No matter if I pass a Boo I always will get a Foo because of polymorphism

Comment: Regarding my first workaround: "as it now takes a Foo, not a T", but my generic delegate has this constraint precisely!! T must be at least Foo or a type derived from Foo

Comment: Can you please tell me how the second workaround could cause a runtime exception? =)

Comment: You aren't passing a more derived class, you're passing a delegate expecting a more derived class, and then passing a less derived class into it. The second will fail if T is, say, Moo, as it cannot be converted to from Foo or Boo.

Comment: Please see my edits, sorry if I insist but I like to go deep down in the things I do not understand. Regarding your Moo case, it does not even compiles... because, well, Moo is not a Foo.. no runtimeException

Comment: After sleeping and reading again this I think it now is clear.. having `SomeGenericClass<Boo>` will lead to having `SomeDelegate<Boo>`, and here it is not legal to pass a Foo as you noticed. Thanks